# Deploying a Django site using apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I've been trying to teach myself to create and deploy Django apps.  I've created a test project and I can browse it using the Django test server.  Now I want to deploy it using apache and mod_wsgi.

I followed the installation instructions at the [Quick Installation Guide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide) and got mod_wsgi installed. I then went through the example in the [Quick Configuration Guide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) and was able to successfully connect to the example output in my browser.

I've now moved on to the [Integration With Django](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango) section and I can't make any progress with it.  Any time I try to browse to the URL I've set up for my project I just see the default apache index page.  I've looked at the apache error log and there are no messages in it (I got a few when I was debugging the first example so I know I'm looking at the correct log).  I tried the initial example wsgi application in the django project folder, but I got the same default index page.  I even set 'LogLevel info' to try and get more detail, but there was none.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is my apach2.conf:

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          150
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
DefaultType text/plain
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
Include httpd.conf
Include ports.conf
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
Include conf.d/
Include sites-enabled/
```

Here is my httpd.com:

```
ServerName HomeServer
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Here is the VitualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ppbase.homeserver
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/projects/ppbase/ppbase
    <Directory /var/projects/ppbase/ppbase>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel info

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/projects/ppbase/django.wsgi
    <Directory /var/projects/ppbase>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the django.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys


projectpath = '/var/projects/ppbase'
projectapppath = '/var/projects/ppbase/ppbase'
if projectpath not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(projectpath)
if projectapppath not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(projectapppath)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ppbase.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget it.  I was being a total idiot.  I'd set up my vhost file, but I hadn't enabled it in apache.

Answer (score 3):

If you get the "It works!" page there is nothing you can see "wrong" in the logs.

Assuming that you're working with virtual hosts, It just means that the default apache config "is a better match" than your django virtual host.

You can define a better rule for your app in the virtual host configuration or, rough and easy, disable the default apache site with (assuming you're on *NIX)

```
sudo a2dissite default
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Comment: I've done that now.  I can no longer see the default index page, but now I'm seeing the output from the first example application (ie 'Hello World').  I've double checked my virtual host files and my django.wsgi file and neither of these are referencing anything which should be outputting that.  Any ideas what now?

Comment: @hellsgate how can we tell, when you haven't posted either the apache conf or the wsgi file?

Comment: @hellsgate as Daniel says, it's hard to say that without the wsgi file and the apache conf. An hint, double check that you put the path to the right wsgi file in the v_host file

Comment: @Daniel & Tommaso: Sorry, I've posted them now in the original question